# how to return a logout validation message on button click in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react component

```
const Header = () => {
return(
    <div role="button" className="user-logout" onClick={logoutUser}>
       <i className="fas fa-sign-out-alt user--nav--icon"></i>
       Logout
    </div>
)}
```

In the above code onClick logout the user gets logged out

```
  const logoutUser = () => {
    dispatch(logout());
    history.push('/login');
  };
```

but I want the user to get a message popup onClcik in a div with `conforming logout` or `cancel`
and then on `confirming logout` it should logout the user

Comment: What have you tried so far, and where are you getting stuck?

Comment: Then you need a state to maintain the popup open and close behaviour . OnClick of div change the state to `true` open the popup now inside the popup have your buttons and on click of confirming logout close the popup and do history.push

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a GET Parameter to the login page like:

```
history.push('/login?logout=1');
```

Then if the login page has this parameter, render your message.

If you don't want to use a parameter, you will have to look for another solution either with react context or react navigation